# How to fix "dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation"

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm compiling linux-4.19(gcc-8.2  bintutils-2.31), however it always fails with errors like:

```
aarch64-oe-linux-ld.bfd: drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ABS32 against `__crc_gsi_write_channel_scratch' can not be used when making a shared object
aarch64-oe-linux-ld.bfd: drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.o:/usr/src/kernel/drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.c:4383:(.data+0x0): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
aarch64-oe-linux-ld.bfd: drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.o:(.data+0x28): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
aarch64-oe-linux-ld.bfd: drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.o:(.data+0x50): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
aarch64-oe-linux-ld.bfd: drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.o:(__verbose+0x0): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
aarch64-oe-linux-ld.bfd: drivers/platform/gsi/gsi.o:(__verbose+0x8): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
```

I've tried below solutions, but these didn't work.

1. Add `-fPIC` flag to the driver
2. Use gcc-7.3 (binutils-2.31)
3. Use binutils-2.33 (gcc-8.2)

Comment: Add "-fpie " to LDFLAGS, fails with "-r and -shared may not be used together"

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the relocation, it is the following warning (should appear before the error)

```
WARNING: EXPORT symbol "gsi_write_channel_scratch" [vmlinux] version generation failed, symbol will not be versioned.
```

If you read more about genksyms [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/6/17/294) you'll understand that it complains because it can't parse something before the place it complains about. In this particular case the issue is a `__packed` return type (which it doesn't understand). `__packed` is only useful when declaring structs and unions. I guess it makes sense for function arguments to serve as documentation, but it's not necessary.

So just drop `__packed` from the previous function `__gsi_update_mhi_channel_scratch` return type and you're set.